# How to add ModelChoice field of django form in template

Tags: python, django

Currently, I am developing a web application. I am using forms to render the fields. I have multiple ModelChoiceField in my application. I am facing error in rendering ModelChoiceField. What I was done is...

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="input-field col s6">
        {{ form.state }} 
        <label for="id_state">State</label>
        {{ form.country }} 
        <label for="id_country">Country</label>
      </div>
</div>
```

[image]
Here state and country are the two ModelChoiceFields. It's only displaying labels and the field is not visible. But when I did inspect element, I am able to see the choices. But in the template it's not showing correctly. What may be the reason?

**UPDATE**
*Form*

```
class CustomerForm(forms.Form):

    name = forms.CharField(label='Customer',max_length=250, required=True)
    image = forms.ImageField(label='Image')
    is_company = forms.BooleanField(label='Is comapany')
    company = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Company.objects.all(), empty_label='Select company', label='Company')
    mobile = forms.IntegerField(label='Mobile')
    email = forms.EmailField(label='Email')
    street = forms.CharField(label='Lane',max_length=300)
    street2 = forms.CharField(label='Street',max_length=300)
    city = forms.CharField(label='City',max_length=250)
    state = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=State.objects.all(), empty_label='Select state', label='State')
    country = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Country.objects.all(), empty_label='Select country' ,label='Country')
    zip = forms.IntegerField(label='Zip Code')
    note = forms.CharField(label='Internal Note',widget=forms.Textarea)
    date_create = forms.DateTimeField()
```

**UPDATE**
*View*

```
def form_view(request,customer_id):
    try:
        customer = Customer.obects.get(pk=pk)
    except Customer.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404('Customer does not exist')
    else:
        data = {
            'name': customer.name,
            'image': customer.image,  
            'is_company': customer.is_company, 
            'company': customer.company, 
            'mobile': customer.mobile, 
            'email': customer.email,
            'street': customer.street, 
            'street2': customer.street2,
            'city': customer.city, 
            'state': customer.state, 
            'country': customer.country, 
            'zip': customer.zip,
            'note': customer.note,  
            }  
        customer_form = CustomerForm(data)
        context = {'form':customer_form}  
        return render(request, 'base/customer_form_view.html', context)
```

Comment: Please, show the corresponding Python view and form code. Also, it's way better to use excellent Django Crispy Forms package for form rendering.

Comment: Why don't you use a model form? Apart from that: Please show the resulting HTML code. Also: `get_object_or_404`raises Http404, not Customer.DoesNotExist.

Comment: @W.Mann. I already added part of th HTML code, where my ModelChoice Field exist

Comment: I guess, this is some kind of copy-paste development. There's no need to wrap `get_object_or_404` in the `try-except` block. Probably condition wrapping the whole view is also not needed (depending on the urlconf). Please, learn the basics of Python/Django, do not develop by copy-pasting random code from Google and SO. Everything is explained in excellent Django Tutorial and docs. Spend at least 30 minutes reading it.

Also, Django `ModelForm` and generic edit views are a proper solution instead of manually copying customer data into the plain form.

Comment: Regarding form rendering: this is definitely a case for django-crispy-forms. If you still want to layout your form manually (pretty bad idea generally as it makes maintenance much harder), open source view in your browser and check what's there in place of form fields.

Comment: @EugeneMorozov. Please don't judge people by just looking on to the code. I am new to Django and still learning. I myself has coded all the above codes which I posted. Please excuse me for my bad practices

Comment: @AKHILMATHEW Why you write the code that you don't understand then? You inserted call to `get_object_or_404` without reading what it does apparently. Because it doesn't raise `Customer.DoesNotExist` exception. It's there exactly to avoid writing this kind of boilerplate code.

Comment: Also, this is definitely a case for `ModelForm`. Copying the model data to and from plain `Form` is a waste of time: `ModelForm` handles all this automatically. If you're learning, you should also learn the best tool for the job. It's explained in Django Tutorial as far as I remember. Do you learn Django without even reading a tutorial?

Comment: @AKHILMATHEW ok, now it is more correct, but it didn't make it better. `get_object_or_404` is there in Django to avoid writing this boilerplate 4 lines in every view. You can replace whole 4 lines with one: `customer = get_object_or_404(Customer, pk=pk)`. Also, open Source View in your browser (<kbd>Ctrl-U</kbd> in Firefox), and post to what HTML code Django transformed your template. This will allow us to solve the problem immediately.

Comment: If you don't see choices in your browser, but can inspect element and see it into HTML source, then it's not realted to Django. Check your CSS and JS, may be you just hide your DOM element.